# Multiple urls to 1 website with a wild card ssl

Tags: iis-6

At the moment, we have 27 single sites in IIS6, all with their own urls, all with the same subdomain, e.g.

https://company1.mycompany.com

https://company2.mycompany.com

etc., etc.

To further complicate things, there is 1 wild card certificate which deals with the subdomain *.mycompany.com and is assigned to each website.

All these websites run under the same codebase.

We want to consolidate all these websites into 1 website.

Are there any issues with having a large number of host headers running under 1 IIS6 site or is there a better way of configuring the site?

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if you can have 27 virtual hosts on 1 IIS6 website, the answer is 'absolutely'.  Virtual hosts scale to hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no issue at all.  Using host headers is more resource friendly than using separate IP addresses since the WWW service needs to manage individual endpoints for separate IP addresses.